# Raspberry Pi and FONA with hologram.io SIM, unable to connect, LCP terminated by peer

Tags: gpio, networking, gsm

Unable to get a Raspberry Pi 4B with FONA module and [hologram.io](https://hologram.io/) SIM card running.  Have followed all tutorial steps on the [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/fona-tethering-to-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black) up to validating a ppp network interface described in the Usage section.

`Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/serial0`, then `Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received`, then `LCP terminated by peer` are showing up in the pppd log.  Also the chat log seems to be okay regardless of the APN (I've used hologram and hologrammm).

Not sure how to get past this point.  The idea eventually is to use the Raspberry Pi and FONA to send receive SMS messages based on sensor signals.

**pppd log**

```
Apr 26 21:41:28 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Apr 26 21:41:29 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T hologram finished (pid 1634), status = 0x0
Apr 26 21:41:29 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Serial connection established.
Apr 26 21:41:29 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: using channel 21
Apr 26 21:41:29 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Using interface ppp0
Apr 26 21:41:29 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/serial0
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4faec5a2> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4faec5a2> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0x4faec5a2> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x4faec5a2]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="raspberrypi" password=<hidden>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x0]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: PAP authentication succeeded
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x0 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [IPCP ConfRej id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x2]
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: LCP terminated by peer
Apr 26 21:41:30 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: sent [LCP TermAck id=0x2]
Apr 26 21:41:33 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Connection terminated.
Apr 26 21:41:33 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Modem hangup
```

**chat log with APN = hologram**

```
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: abort on (DELAYED)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: abort on (ERROR)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: abort on (+CGATT: 0)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: send (AT^M)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: timeout set to 12 seconds
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: expect (OK)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: AT^M^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: OK
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: send (ATH^M)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: expect (OK)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: ^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: ATH^M^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: OK
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: send (ATE1^M)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: expect (OK)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: ^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: ATE1^M^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: OK
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: send (AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","hologram","",0,0^M)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: expect (OK)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: ^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","hologram","",0,0^M^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: OK
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: send (ATD*99#^M)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: timeout set to 22 seconds
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: expect (CONNECT)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: ^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: ATD*99#^M^M
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: CONNECT
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi chat[1714]: send (^M)
Apr 26 21:44:57 raspberrypi pppd[1632]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T hologram finished (pid 1713), status = 0x0
```

**chat log with APN = hologrammm**

```
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: OK
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: send (AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","hologrammm","",0,0^M)
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: expect (OK)
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: ^M
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","hologrammm","",0,0^M^M
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: OK
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: send (ATD*99#^M)
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: timeout set to 22 seconds
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: expect (CONNECT)
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: ^M
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: ATD*99#^M^M
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: CONNECT
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]:  -- got it
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi chat[1834]: send (^M)
Apr 26 21:49:17 raspberrypi pppd[1777]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T hologrammm finished (pid 1833), status = 0x0
```

Comment: So, you have followed all the steps from a tutorial. Did they all succeed? Did some fail? Which ones?

Comment: The post describes the point at which the configuration failed - validating the ppp network interface.

Comment: Could you finally solve this? I have the same issue but just with some modems.

Comment: @vanthome Never did solve this.